# Ionic deploy is not working after the first application update

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm using the simple example of Deploy from here: http://docs.ionic.io/docs/deploy-quick-start. Its works, but only the first time. When app is updated the first time, I can't update it anymore, I'm getting error: `IONIC_DEPLOY_MISSING_PACKAGE`

But I don't change code after the first update, just deploy new version with `ionic upload`.

Comment: This service has not been official release, I'm using it now, in the last day it work for me. But now I can't get it updated. Maybe because of the plugin or server issue.

Comment: Yes, maybe you're right

Comment: You should use it during the development, don't use it for production app. Currently I have the issue when download the update, it stuck on 50% percent and crash the app.

Comment: I don't talk about production, it doesn't works even for dev:)

Comment: I know, but sometimes it works very well. I use it more than a month without any problem, but this week I update to Ionic v2 and ... not work any more.